# How to fix: 'subscript out of range', Run time error '9'

Tags: excel, vba

New to VBA, is issue seems to be the following line,

```
Set NoMonths = Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("C13")
```

Unsure why as in cell c13 on sheet4 there contains a number value for example 5.

Can someone help please.

Full code:

```
Sub DefferedRev()

    Set NoMonths = Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("C13")
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim q As Integer


    If Worksheets("Sheet13").Range("B40") = Worksheets("Sheet13").Range("C82") Then
        For i = 5 To 7
            Cells(48, i).Value = 0
        Next i
    Else
        For i = 5 To 7
            q = (i Mod NoMonths) - 5
            Dim VectorToSum() As String
            ReDim VectorToSum(1 To q)
            For w = 1 To q
                VectorToSum(w) = (Worksheets("Sheet13").Cells(38, i).Value * Worksheets("Sheet13").Cells(7, i).Value) / (NoMonths * NoMonths - w)
            Next w
            ValueIn = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(VectorToSum)

            Cells(48, i).Value = ValueIn
        Next i
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Suggest you don't have a worksheet named "Sheet4" in the active workbook. (You should get in the habit of declaring all variables.)

Comment: Remove "Set" from line Set NoMonths = Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("C13") as you don't seem to be using NoMonths as Range Object.

Comment: My 1st thought is you don't have a sheet named "Sheet4", but now that I have looked at your code more closely. It appears you are using NoMonths as a variant, as suggested earlier, you don't set a variant.

Comment: @Davesexcel, If `"Sheet4"` would be present in the current project, VBA would create a `Variant/Object/Range` type variable for `NoMonths`. The code would have worked (at least past that specific line generating the error)

Answer (score 2):

> Subscript out of range

means that the `Worksheets()` property cannot find a worksheet named `Sheet4`.

1. Make sure the sheet name has no additional spaces before, after or between `Sheet4`. In case of any doubt rename it to ensure correct naming of the sheet.
2. In case of working with multiple workbooks (or in general following a good practice) specify in which workbook your worksheet is by using:

   ```
   Set NoMonths = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("C13") 'ThisWorkbook is the workbook this code is in
   ```

---

Additionally I recommend to use `Option Explicit` and declare all your variables proplery before you use them. For Example:

```
Dim NoMonths As Range
Set NoMonths = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("C13")
```

Further if you use `Cells(48, i).Value = 0` you don't define in which workbook this cell is. So Excel makes a guess and it might fail. **Always** specify a workbook/worksheet for all `Range`, `Cells`, `Rows`, `Columns` objects.

```
Thisworkbook.Worksheets("Sheet13").Cells(48, i).Value = 0
```

Better approach is to set the worksheets to a variable to make your code short and clean and re-use that variable.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Thisworkbook.Worksheets("Sheet13")

ws.Cells(48, i).Value = 0
```

Finally I highly recommend to use meaningful variable names and worksheet names. `Sheet13` and `Sheet4` are pretty bad choices for names. Choosing a good name should be the very fist thing you do. Because if you do that last you will have to change it everywhere in your code.

---

So in the end your code should be something like this:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub DefferedRev()
    Dim NoMonths As Range
    Set NoMonths = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("C13")

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet13")


    If ws.Range("B40").Value = ws.Range("C82").Value Then
        'For i = 5 To 7
        '    ws.Cells(48, i).Value = 0
        'Next i

        'this loop can be written at once (faster!)
        'replace it with the following line
        ws.Range(ws.Cells(48, 5), ws.Cells(48, 7)).Value = 0
    Else
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 5 To 7
            Dim q As Long
            q = (i Mod NoMonths) - 5

            Dim VectorToSum() As String
            ReDim VectorToSum(1 To q)

            Dim w As Long
            For w = 1 To q
                VectorToSum(w) = (ws.Cells(38, i).Value * ws.Cells(7, i).Value) / (NoMonths * NoMonths - w)
            Next w

            ws.Cells(48, i).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(VectorToSum)
        Next i
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: As it is not being used as a range object, would it be better for NoMonths be an Integer? e.g. `Dim NoMonths as Integer` and `NoMonths = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("C13").Value`?

Comment: @Gravitate Yes, you can do that. But I recommend `Long` as there is no benefit in using `Integer` over `Long`.

Comment: Hmm... I've never really thought about that. Integer is just my go to numeric type (unless I specifically need larger values). Thanks! Presumably, integer does use less memory? Just not enough to make any noticeable difference?

Comment: @Gravitate Actually using less memory *would* be a reason to prefer `Integer` (even if it would only be a tiny benefit is would be a benefit). But in VBA it does not use less memory it uses the exactly same amount of memory as a `Long` does but at the same time it still cannot take as large numbers as `Long`. So there is only disadvantages. I recommend to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409117/why-use-integer-instead-of-long/26409520#26409520) if you are interested why. • Note this is valid for VBA and does not apply to other coding languages.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I will take a look.

Comment: Thank you, this has been very helpful. I have ran into another issue though when redefining the VectorToSum to be `ReDim VectorToSum(0 To q - 1)`  (an empty vector of lengh q) I am getting the same error, why may this be. @Pᴇʜ

Comment: @CharlesEwing make sure `q - 1` is `> 0` if it is `0` or negative  the array cannot be defined. Check which value `q` has in case of error.